# How to create a close button in javascript tha closes current div and make another div appears?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```js
function show(id){
    document.getElementById('close_btn').style.display="block";
    switch(id) {
        case 'item_1_red':
            document.getElementById('visible').style.display="none";
            document.getElementById('1').style.display="block";
        break;

        case 'item_2_red':
            document.getElementById('visible').style.display="none";
            document.getElementById('2').style.display="block";
        break;

        case 'item_3_red':
            document.getElementById('visible').style.display="none";
            document.getElementById('3').style.display="block";
        break;

        case 'item_4_red':
            document.getElementById('visible').style.display="none";
            document.getElementById('4').style.display="block";
        break;
    };  
}

function close_f() {
    document.getElementById('visible').style.display="block";
}
```

```css
.block-1{
    width: 100%;
    margin:0 auto;
    padding: 0px;
}

.visible{
    width: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.invisible{
    width: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="close_btn" id="close_btn" onclick="close_f()" style="display:none;">fermer </div>

<div class="block-1">
    <ul class="visible" id='visible'>
        <li class="item-1"><div class="item_1_red" id="item_1_red" onclick="show(this.id)">item1</div></li>
        <li class="item-2"><div class="item_2_red" id="item_2_red" onclick="show(this.id)">item2</div></li>
        <li class="item-3"><div class="item_3_red" id="item_3_red" onclick="show(this.id)">item3</div></li>
        <li class="item-4"><div class="item_4_red" id="item_4_red" onclick="show(this.id)">item4</div></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="block-2">
    <ul class="invisible" id="invisible">
        <li class="item-1"><div class="item_1_red" id="1" style="display:none;">hi i'm item1</div></li>
        <li class="item-2"><div class="item_2_red" id="2" style="display:none;">hi i'm item2</div></li>
        <li class="item-3"><div class="item_3_red" id="3" style="display:none;">hi i'm item3</div></li>
        <li class="item-4"><div class="item_4_red" id="4" style="display:none;">hi i'm item4</div></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I want to have at the first time only a list of 4 items, when i choose to click on item 1, the first `ul` (visible) disappears and i'll get only :"hi i'm item1" with button "close" if i click on close, the "hi i'm item1" disappears and let place to the first div : visible (the first 4 items list) and then i can click on any item i want, that will make div :invisible appears and shows : hi i'm itemX

take a look to my scripts please

any help please ?

[here is jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/86xz90mc/1/)

Edit : Also i need to have buttons "next" "preview" to navigate between items (when clicked on item1 in the first ul, it will make :"hi i'm item 1", if i click on "next" it will make : "hi i'm item 2" etc.. this [EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/pitmit/rr8eu5ev/1/) seems to be a part of the answer, i'm customizing it for 2 hours but not working for me, any help please ?

Comment: Please create fiddle.

Comment: i'v just edited my question, thank you @rajuGT

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/86xz90mc/1/ Do you want this?

Comment: hi @nevermind yes the "fermer" button appears, but if you see "hi im item" stay when we click on "fermer" (means "close" in french) when i click on it i want to get only the first ul (list of 4 items) not wit hi im item

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're going to do this kind of thing, I'd strongly recommend you learn and use jQuery. It makes things like this a snap. see this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rr8eu5ev/

HTML:

```
<div class="close_btn" id="close_btn" onclick="close_f()" style="display:none;">close </div>



 <div class="block-1">
<ul class="visible" id='visible'>
    <li data-elem="item_1_red">item1</li>
    <li data-elem="item_2_red">item2</li>
    <li data-elem="item_3_red">item3</li>
    <li data-elem="item_4_red">item4</li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="block-2">
<ul class="invisible" id="invisible">
    <li id="item_1_red">hi i'm item1</li>
    <li id="item_2_red">hi i'm item2</li>
    <li id="item_3_red">hi i'm item3</li>
    <li id="item_4_red">hi i'm item4</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.block-1{
width: 100%;
margin:0 auto;
padding: 0px;
}
.visible{
width: 50%;
margin: 0 auto;
}

.invisible{
width: 50%;
margin: 0 auto;
}

.invisible li { display: none; }
```

javascript:

```
$(function(){
    $('#visible li').click(function(){
        var elem = $(this).data('elem');   
        $('#' + elem).show();
        $('.close_btn').show();
        $('#visible').hide();
    });

    $('.close_btn').click(function(){
        $('#visible').show();
        $('#invisible li').hide();
        $('.close_btn').hide();
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much Gregg it works great. Now i'm facing a "new" problem, what if i wanted to add two buttons "next" and "last" that appear with the second ul (hi im itemX) to slide left and right ?

Comment: Example : first i click on "item1", that make "hi i'm item1" with button close and : next + last, if i'll click on next i'll get "hi i'm item2" if i click on last i'll get "hi i'm item4", i'm working on it for 3hours now without success

Comment: Awesome Gregg that's all what i wanted thank you very much ! You just make me LOVE jquery !!! have to learn it

Answer (score 1):

You're not hiding the "Hi I'm itemX" divs in the close function.  Here's an updated jsfiddle that *I think* does what you want.

I just added

```
document.getElementById('1').style.display="none";
```

for each each of the numbered divs (http://jsfiddle.net/86xz90mc/3/).

You could also make the close function take an ID parameter and then pass the element's ID in so you don't have to hardcode it.

Comment: Hi ashanan it works great, thank you very much, i just want to learn it on jquery